# Generating XML using ViewModelAsXML

Tags: mdriven

How do I render a XMLdocument containing these `xsi` adm `xmlns` tags with corresponding `URI`, I have tried the NodeName tagged value but without luck... Replace would do it but is there a more robust way?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I myself would use the opendocumentreport logic with a static template that holds xml documents with all namespaces and details:

```
vCurrent_GoogleFeed2.FeedResult:=vCurrent_GoogleFeed2.opendocumentreportasblob( GoogleFeed.Viewmodels.GoogleFeedReport ).asstring
```

And my template looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Very effective resolution! "I didn't see the forest due to all the trees" (Swedish expression)